# What does "[I:let nr " mean?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, spf13vim

I'm using spf-13 to config my vim. And I find a keymap like this:

```
nmap <leader>ff [I:let nr = input("Which one: ")<Bar>exe "normal " . nr ."[\t"<CR>
```

After try and search, I still can't find what does `[I` and `[\t` mean.

Answer (score 2):

No. You didn't really search:

```
:help [I
```

If you scroll up a bit you'll find where that mapping comes from.